# Posting the results of a form to another form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the app I'm currently writing, I need to send the results of one form to another. I'm not using nested  tags, nor am I using partial views.

I've rendered the inner form like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var item in @Model)
    {   

            <input type="checkbox" name="@model.item" id="" align="right" checked="true"/>
            <label for="@model.item">@model.item</label> <br />

    }

        <input type="submit" value="Save Settings" />
}
```

And rendered the outer form like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="settings-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.anotherItem)
    </div>

    <div class="settings-label">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.anotherItem)
    </div>

    <a href="../innerform/innerform">Choose inner form stuff</a><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Save Settings" />
}
```

The outer form is a list of different types representing the settings of my website, whilst the inner form is a list, of a particular setting.

Answer (score 0):

To pass values from one for to another you can simply POST the data/model to a Action and then send the data/model to another View

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OutterFormHandler(MyModel data)
    {
        //do something with data
        return View("AnotherView", data);
    }
```

Is this what you're looking for???